# What causes zoom jumps/imperfections in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, browser, zooming, jexceljs

We are testing out a Javascript "Excel" library called jExcel and encountered an issue we have no idea if its a problem in the library or some other (browser?)setting. We are testing with the following example https://bossanova.uk/jspreadsheet/v4/examples/tabs

If one first zoom (CTRL -) to 80% in the browser and then double click in a cell. The whole page and table jumps slightly. This does not happen when using default zoom. Is this due to some rounding off error in the library or what causes this and what is this kind of issue called? Is there any idea of trying to fix this, if so where to start look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ouroborus did you also try other zoom levels lke 67% for instance?

Comment: Yes, I was unable to reproduce this at any zoom level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Ouroborus See video here of what it looks like on my PC, maybe its a Windows 11 issue? https://streamable.com/e68og3